# Who consecrated Bishop Heahmund?

Tags: bishops, apostolic-succession

Who consecrated [Heahmund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heahmund) as the [Bishop of Sherborne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishop_of_Sherborne_(ancient)), What was his Apostolic Lineage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **we do not know**.

This information is now lost because historical documents do not contain this information.

In fact we do not know exactly what date he was even consecrated a bishop.

> Heahmund was a medieval Bishop of Sherborne. He was a warrior-bishop and he was killed fighting against the Danes for the Anglo-Saxon King Æthelred I of Wessex and his brother Alfred.
>
> Heahmund was consecrated in 867 or 868. He died at the Battle of Meretun in 871. As his death is assigned to 22 March in the English calendar of saints the battle and his death can be dated 22 March 871. He was buried at Keynsham in Somerset.
>
> Heahmund is venerated as a saint in the Eastern Orthodox Church and Roman Catholic Church.
>
> — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heahmund)

His feast day is March 22.

Unfortunately this is an obscure saint and few details have come down to us. He was certainly consecrated by a local bishop of England. My personal guess would be that the Archbishop of Canterbury was the main consecrator.

Comment: Heahmund co-signed a charter [Cotton MS Augustus II 17](https://searcharchives.bl.uk/primo-explore/fulldisplay?vid=IAMS_VU2&docid=IAMS040-001102021&lang=en_US&fromRedirectFilter=true); it can be [seen online](https://www.bl.uk/manuscripts/Viewer.aspx?ref=cotton_ms_augustus_ii_17_f001r). The names of signatories are in columns at the bottom, with [Ceolnoth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceolnoth) as "arch episcopus" in the top left and Heahmund "elect episcopus" just under. So he was in Canterbury in the company of its archbishop about the time of his consecration - probably not a coincidence!

Comment: An alternative potential consecrator would have been [Ealhferth, Bishop of Winchester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ealhferth) as more likely to be near that part of Wessex.